# Replace <script src = jquery.js> by node_module in hybrid application (AngularJS - Angular) et Webpack

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular, webpack-4, ts-loader

I'm facing a problem that everyone has already met but despite all the proposed solutions, none correct my problem.

We actually have an hybrid application (AngularJS and Angular8) using Webpack4 and ts-loader. We loaded all our libraries using  tag and everything worked fine.

My actual work is to remove these script tags and set up node_modules instead.
Everything works except jquery.

Indeed, in development mode, it's ok because I use devtool : 'eval-source-map' and in that situation, jquery is found everywhere but when I want to generate my bundle file in production mode without using source map, jquery is no more found.

And the fact using source map makes the file considerably bigger.

Here is my webpack configs :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, '/main.ts'),
        dashboard: path.join(__dirname, '/main.dashboard.ts'),
    },
    // devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/dist",
        pathinfo: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /(.+)?angular(\/)core(.+)?/,
            path.join(__dirname, '/'), //location of src
            {} //a map of our routes
        ),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};
```

In my package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31"
  },
```

Any Help would be appreciate,
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to the `angular.json`. Find the property "scripts" (you may have more than one of those) and add

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

(or compatible, dependent on the actual path to jQuery's dist).

Comment: thanks for reply, you mean in the package.json of the angular node_modules ?

Comment: We actually are in hybrid mode and we're not used angularCLI to add angular to our existing project so I don't have any angular.json file in my project

Comment: Oh. That changes things a little, because this is a go-to way of adding 3rd-party scripts to Angular app. How do you build your app, then, without all the goodness provided by angular cli?

Comment: manually, the file in charge of that looks like : 

<code>
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app']);
});
</code>